# Rewrite URL and Redirect to New Format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I was wondering if I could get some help changing a URL.

I would like to change and match all city/state URL's to a different format and have them redirect to the newer URL if someone lands on them.

I would like to change and redirect:

```
http://www.domain.com/FL/Miami.html

to 

http://www.domain.com/miami-fl/
```

The rule I have right now that I would like to change and redirect to new one:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?st=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the case doesn't matter, you can just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([^/-]+)\.html$ index.php?st=$2&city=$1 [L]
```